# Why doesn't 'sudo' skip hostname-checking when the command can be run on 'ALL' hosts?

Tags: sudo, hostname, hosts

The `sudoers` file provides a way to limit which "runas" entries apply to which hosts. When running a command with `sudo`, the hostname is checked against the hosts on which a "runas" entry applies.

When the host-name is misconfigured, this can cause sudo to take a long time trying to resolve the hostname, and [sometimes it will entirely prevent users from using `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/q/59458/236343).

But most `sudoers` configurations I've seen only ever use the `ALL` host alias, meaning that it shouldn't matter what host the user is on. Why does `sudo` even perform the check in this case, since it can cause problems?

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of trying to read Todd Miller's mind, I'll just say that sudo is configured to report the hostname in the logging it does, so it has to look it up. See the log_denial function at:

https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/f19c689a2ded/plugins/sudoers/logging.c